# CLSID for x264 DirectShow filter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow, video-capture, x264

I have used [x264 DirectShow filter](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2009/05/20/monogram-x264-encoder-1050/) from Monogram for decoding h264 avc video , i need to  create intrance and add filter to graph in directshow , i checked the CLSID of it from grapthEdit , and that is 'x264' , i guess that to create instance we need the GUID for that filter , i have no clue how can i create filter instance using 'x264' value.

I am using directshow with vc++

Can any body have idea on this???

Comment: Use the CLSIDFromProgID helper function.  The progid is a string, it ought to resemble something like 'Monogram.x264'.

Comment: Most likely there is no `ProgID` there. OP has to use `MIDL_INTERFACE` to hardcode the `CLSID` (or use `CLSIDFromString`, or `declspec(uuid(` + `__uuidof`).

Comment: ... oops, `DEFINE_GUID` instead of `MIDL_INTERFACE` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this filter is open source, you only need to watch in the right headers. You just need to copy CLSID_MonogramX264 from [here](http://dev.monogram.sk/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=x264_enc&path=/trunk/src/x264_types.h) and create the filter with `CoCreateInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Monogram Graph Studio to see an CLSID, as I remember than I checked it last time all was OK.